# Configure Active Directory to allow LDAPmodify

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to integrate a Microsoft AD service with existing Linux services.

The AD server is set up to allow LDAP enquiries and has a read-only user to allow this. I can successfully retrieve data using ldapsearch.

If I try to connect using `ldaps://`, I get connection refused.

I am new to MS AD / DC and am just feeling my way around. I've had 2 days down a Google rabbit hole trying to work out how to configure this setup, but all I can see are posts about setting up the Linux / LDAP side.

I am an administrator on the AD server, can log in, and can modify the AD contents using the native windows tools. If I try to do an ldapsearch binding to my credentials, the connection fails.

Does anyone have links to doc's on how to

1. enable `ldaps://`
2. obtain a certificate (`.pem`) file to connect securely
3. Create an AD user with permission to allow LDAP Add/Modify/Delete

I have followed numerous posts about setting up the client side, with and without SASL.

SASL connections failed as I could not find out how to generate the certificate.

ldapsearch also failed on all credentials except the ldap read only user.

Initially I just want to be able to successfully do a secure ldapsearch with different credentials before moving on to add/modify/delete

Comment: The real question is, why do you think your users _don't_ have permission to use LDAP? (The LDAP service is literally the core of AD; it's the "directory" in "active directory". It's what the native Windows tools use.) Don't confuse SASL and SSL/TLS – SASL does not use certificates. (SASL GSSAPI provides LDAP security similar to that of SSL/TLS.)

Comment: In answer to your first part. If I do a LDAPSearch on any user other than the LDAPViewer user I get bad connection.
I can bind using any user's credentials but none of them can search.
I have found out how to create a user with modify permissions and that seems to have worked.
However I cannot set passwords without first setting up a secure connection.
This is the bit I'm currently working on.

Comment: I have managed to follow instructions to set up an LDAPUpdate user, and using LDIFDE I have managed to create users using an LDIF file. However, this still does not allow me to set a user password, or enable the user.
I have also managed to connect to the AD using PHP_LDAP to create users, but again I cannot set a password or enable an account.
I have created a  security certificate, and exported a base64 encoded certificate file (.CER)
However, I cannot find out how to get PHP_LDAP to use this certificate to create a secure connection.